# What is the equivalent of EOF in Bindingsource?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can you help me with my problem in navigating BindingSource.

I want to convert this vb6 code in vb.net using BindingSource

```
Do Until recordSet.EOF
   if isnull(resordSet!FieldName)=true then
      recordSet.delete
   end if
 recordset.movenext
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the entire loop with [`BindingSource.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.clear.aspx):

> The Clear method removes all elements from the underlying list
>   represented by the List property and sets the Count property to zero.
>
> This method raises the ListChanged event.

Comment: i'm not clearing na bindingsource what i want is like this:Do Until recordSet.EOF
   if isnull(resordSet!FieldName)=true then
      recordSet.delete
   end if
 recordset.movenext
loop convert this code

Comment: that loop clears a recordset. If that recordset is bound to a control (as your question implies), then they have the same effect. If not, I suggest you make your question clearer.